# Viber REST API[GATEWAY_TIMEOUT]

Tags: json

I am making REST API call to Viber back-end but intermittently I am getting 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT error.

Are there any limitations when we send multiple requests to Viber back-end at the same time?

Comment: Did you figure out the solution on this? Also is there any demo account that we can play around with an audience more than 300?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they have limitations. See [Broadcast Message](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#broadcast-message) section.

> Maximum total JSON size of the request is 30kb. The maximum list
>   length is 300 receivers. The Broadcast API is used to send messages to
>   multiple recipients with a rate limit of **500 requests in a 10 seconds**
>   window.